# Comparing two csv files in Python

Tags: python, csv

I am new to Python so still struggling with csv files.
I've got two csv files:

```
students.csv:
name,subject1,subject2,subject3
Student1,MN1,MN2,MN3
Student2,BN1,BN2,BN3
Student3,MN4,MN5,MN6
Student4,MN2,MN3
Student5,MN7,MN1,MN2
Student6,MN8
Student7,MN1,MN2,MN3
Student8,BN4,BN5,BN1

subject.csv:
subject,VM
MN1,VM for MN1 is powering on
MN2,VM for MN2 is powering on
MN3,VM for MN3 is powering on
BN1,VM for BN1 is powering on
BN2,VM for BN2 is powering on
BN3,VM for BN3 is powering on
MN4,VM for MN4 is powering on
MN5,VM for MN5 is powering on
MN6,VM for MN5 is powering on
```

My script needs to check whether student is registered for the subject or not (this part is done as I asked for some help before)

After that, if student is registered, script will need to go to the second file and find a match between the subject student registered for with VM and output the corresponding VM.

If student is not registered, it needs to print something like ("You are not registered for this subject, please enter another subject") and start script for the start ( this part I am also having issues with)..

My code:

```
#!c:/Python36/python.exe
import csv
import sys


data = {i[0]:i[1:] for i in csv.reader(open('students.csv'))}
data2 = {j[0]:j[1:] for j in csv.reader(open('subjects.csv'))}

Name = input("Please provide your name: ")
Subject = input("Please provide your Subject: ")

    for data[Subject] in data2[VM]: # problem is somewhere around here I suppose
    if Subject in data[Name]:
        print ("you are registered - ", VM)
    else:
        print("you are not registered")
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand, you need to look up the subject from the 2nd file and print the corresponding line for the subject. If I understood correctly, then you actually don't need to iterate through the data2, rather use an infinite loop. Something like following:

```
i = 0
while i == 0:
    Name = input("Please provide your name (q to quit): ")
    if Name == 'q':
        i = 1
    else:
        Subject = input("Please provide your Subject: ")
        if Subject in data[Name]:
            if Subject in data2.keys():
                print ("you are registered - ", data2[Subject])
            else:
                print("The VM for the subject doesn't exist")
        else:
            print("you are not registered")
```

Your initial code had the indentation wrong, but I am assuming that is unintentional :) Also it was looking for the variable VM, which you don't define anywhere. Another thing, is if you are reading the csv files with csv.reader, your data will have an extra key that with your table headings. like this:

data:

```
{'Student1': ['MN1', 'MN2', 'MN3'],
 'Student2': ['BN1', 'BN2', 'BN3'],
 'Student3': ['MN4', 'MN5', 'MN6'],
 'Student4': ['MN2', 'MN3'],
 'Student5': ['MN7', 'MN1', 'MN2'],
 'Student6': ['MN8'],
 'Student7': ['MN1', 'MN2', 'MN3'],
 'Student8': ['BN4', 'BN5', 'BN1'],
 'name': ['subject1', 'subject2', 'subject3']}
```

data2:

```
{'BN1': ['VM for BN1 is powering on'],
 'BN2': ['VM for BN2 is powering on'],
 'BN3': ['VM for BN3 is powering on'],
 'MN1': ['VM for MN1 is powering on'],
 'MN2': ['VM for MN2 is powering on'],
 'MN3': ['VM for MN3 is powering on'],
 'MN4': ['VM for MN4 is powering on'],
 'MN5': ['VM for MN5 is powering on'],
 'MN6': ['VM for MN5 is powering on'],
 'subject': ['VM']}
```

Get rid of the extra entries with the following:

```
del data['name']
del data2['subject']
```

Also, I highly recommend that you look into the Python Pandas library, which should take care of these trivial things. It might not seem important now, but when you are working with large amount of data, the in-built pandas optimizations will come in handy. Plus you can do a lot more with the library and it's a good idea to have experience with libraries that is being used by everyone to handle csvs and data in general.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, man. I really appreciate it. Could you please explain where is "data2.keys()" coming from?
Actually I just started looking at pandas, thanks for your advice. 
By the way, do you know if there is something similar in php cause I was thinking to execute this script through php but I guess my free web hosting will not allow me to do that so I will probably need to rewrite it in php?

Comment: The "data2.keys()" gets all the keys in a dictionary. I use that to see if the subject the student is registered with has an entry in the subject file. The subject MN8 doesn't have an entry in the second csv, so it is a guard code. You can read up about python dictionary on the python docs. As for php, I am sorry, I don't know php so can't help there. Also, if the answer worked for you, please mark it as the answer and upvote it, so that future searchers can know which was the correct solution :)

Comment: Thanks for that. I have got one more question - if in subjects.csv there is web link instead of just text saying VM for..., will it be possible to run this link instead printing text... I have tried a few ways but it says TypeError: startfile: filepath should be string, bytes or os.PathLike, not NoneType...Any ideas?

Comment: You'd have to do some parsing, I guess. You can use regex to check if it is in an http format and use the webbrowser library to open it. A google search for checking weblinks will give you a lot of good results :)
As for the errors you are getting, it is hard to tell without seeing the actual code or data. From what I can gather, you are trying to pass an empty variable (at least NoneType pops up in that particular time)

Comment: Thanks man, I made it work through regex ;)
Finally done with my algorithm. The last challenge is to run it in php..